# Reducing whitespace when option not selected in HTML

Tags: html, tags, google-forms

I'm using Form Mule to generate an auto email on the submission of a Google Form. The email is pulling information from the Google Sheet responses, where users may select some options but not others. In the email, I've included the tags from the form so it will only populate the responses they chose. The problem is, it creates a lot of whitespace for the options not selected.

Let's say the customer only selects 1 and 10, there would be 8 blank lines of space between their answers. Is there HTML code I can insert to remove that blank space when an answer isn't selected?

```
<b>You have registered for the following: </b><p><<Option1>><br><<Option2>><<Option3>><br><<Option4>><br><<Option5>><br><<Option6>><br><<Option7>><br><<Option8>><br><<Option9>><br><<Option10>>
```

Comment: Make a state for selected option and then show only those which are selected

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? I have a very limited HTML ability